# Email & Move Files Recursively

Tags: powershell

I am looking to create a script that emails and moves files recursively for all the files in a specified folder.

So for each file it will:
Email File1
move File1
Email File2
Move File2
Etc.

Now when I run the script below I get the following message:
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'c:\Test\Out\'

ForEach ($file in $files) 
    {$smtpServer = “mail.dlabs.local”

    $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $att = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($file.FullName)
    $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

    $msg.From = “test@dlabs.co.uk”
    $msg.To.Add(”test@dlabs.co.uk”)
    $msg.Subject =  ("Test Message "+ $file.Name)
    $msg.Body = “”
    $msg.Attachments.Add($att)

    $smtp.Send($msg)

    Move-Item $moveFile.FullName 'c:\Test\Sent'}
```

If anyone could help me with this it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because a file handle is already opened for the file you're trying to move.

The Net.Mail.Attachment implements IDisposable, so to release the file lock you should call $att.Dispose()

Answer (score 1):

Call `.Dispose()` on the msg object.

If that doesn't work, you may also want to call .Disposse on the Attachment object first, and then `.Dispose()` on the msg object.

(I think you only have to call `.Dispose()` on the msg object, but I can't remember...been a while since I tested that code).